# How to update new rows on access table from Excel (not linked table) keeping old data

Tags: excel, vba

Need some help with a table in Excel, This is the problem:

I have a table in Excel (with 26000 rows), and this table contains several parameters that can be repeated, as company, city or product, but always with different reference number.

A person for another department included this table on access an added an extra column (surcharge) to write a surcharge value for every row (yes, 26000 rows). this is how this table looks like in MS Access:

[image: original excel and original access]

Here comes the modification: every week, a new report is generated, creating a new excel table, where some prices change and new rows are added from the original excel table.

As you can see on image, there are new prices and new rows (in orange). 
What I would need is to update this changes (prices and new rows) in my access table, so the gaps on the extra column can be filled every week and have it updated.

The access would look something like this:

[image: modification in excel and how it should be modified in access]

all this, with 26000 rows..

Answer (score 0):

Please try this . . . .

```
Sub UpdateAccessFromExcel()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim r As Long
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim strSQL As String

    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
        "C:\Users\Northwind.mdb"
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.Open strConn

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lastrow = .Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
        lastcolumn = .Range("A2").End(xlToRight).Column
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(lastrow, 1), .Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn))
    End With

        'therow = 1

        For i = 2 To lastrow
            'r = rng.Row
            'If r > 1 Then
                strSQL = "UPDATE PersonInformation SET " & _
                    "FName='" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value & "', " & _
                    "LName='" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i).Value & "', " & _
                    "Address='" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i).Value & "', " & _
                    "Age=" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & i).Value & " WHERE " & _
                    "ID=" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value
                conn.Execute strSQL
            'End If
            'r = r + 1
        Next i

    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much Andre, I am going to try your code right now and I 'll revert. Thanks again!!!!!!